# Can org-mode babel tangle produce leiningen directories?

Tags: clojure, org-mode, leiningen, literate-programming, org-babel

We want to automate the production of a Leiningen project tree
  entirely from an org-mode babel file. We want to do this so that we
  can also create beautiful, typeset documentation via
  `org-latex-export-to-pdf`. We want no less than full literate
  programming in Clojure from org-mode.

The following command:

```
$ lein new ex1
```

produces a tree that looks like this:

```
ex1
ex1/.gitignore
ex1/doc
ex1/doc/intro.md
ex1/project.clj
ex1/README.md
ex1/resources
ex1/src
ex1/src/ex1
ex1/src/ex1/core.clj
ex1/test
ex1/test/ex1
ex1/test/ex1/core_test.clj
```

We want to do the identical thing just by running
`org-babel-tangle`, and no more, in our org-mode buffer in
emacs.

A difficulty arises: whereas `tangle` is happy to produce
files in existing subdirectories like `src` and `test`, it seems reluctant to produce the subdirectories if they don't exist. That means we must
create the directory structure by some other means -- unless we can
get `tangle` to do it for us, and that's the subject of this
*StackOverflow* question.

There are six files in the directory structure created by `Leiningen`. I can remove them all and re-create them from my org-file with `BEGIN_SRC` blocks such as the following

```
#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :tangle ./ex1/src/ex1/core.clj
(ns ex1.core)

(defn foo
  "I don't do a whole lot."
  [x]
  (println x "Hello, World!"))
#+END_SRC
```

Notice particularly the name of the subdirectory path

```
#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :tangle ./ex1/src/ex1/core.clj
```

All is well if our directory structure already exists. org-mode's `tangle` will
create or update all six files described above and create new files in any existing directory. We don't know how to
get `tangle` to produce the directories; it complains that there is no such
directory.

A copy of the desired `.org` file can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1997638/ex1.org) if you would like more details.

Comment: Have you considered fogus.github.io/marginalia/ as a starting point?

Comment: looking at it now -- didn't know about it

Comment: my .2c org-babel is much more powerfull than marginalia

Comment: Our use-case for babel is the we have *a lot* of mathematics that we need type-set in `LaTeX`, plus lots of diagrams a-la `Tikz` and `PGF`, and we really want the Clojure code *right next door* so we have a fighting chance that the code and the documentation will not drift. Our document / code / project will run to well over 1k pages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible use the following header in the begin_src section,

```
:mkdirp yes
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify in one place that *every* `BEGIN_SRC` in the file should have `:mkdirp yes`?

Comment: if you use noweb you can have one section that collects all snippets and creates directory that way you do not have to add that to all source headers

Comment: for reference, https://raw.github.com/nakkaya/nakkaya.com/master/resources/posts/2011-06-29-ferret-an-experimental-clojure-compiler.org uses org-babel with noweb most of his posts are written with org-babel

Comment: you can also assign a noweb name to a section so all of the section ends up in a file etc.

Comment: @Red.Cabin: yes, you can specify in one place that every code block must have default properties. Put the following somewhere at the top of your file:

Comment: #+PROPERTY: mkdirp yes

Comment: @fniessen this was a helpful comment, but I could not make it work.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin This is probably long since past its usefulness, but future readers note that you must `C-c C-c` the line to apply the setting.  (It will be automatically set the next time you find the file.)

Answer (score 0):

FYI There's now a lein project template for using org based projects:

https://github.com/thi-ng/thing-babel